# Glassfish 4.1.0 Application Deployment and ManagedExecutorService with Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, glassfish

I am using ManagedExecutorService to manage Runnables in an Application. When I deploy new code, the Application is reconstructed, but the Runnables listed to ManagedExecutorService do not get cancelled. Since the Application is reconstructed, should the Runnables not stop? The underlying Java code that makes up the Runnables may change with a deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Add a member to the Application extension that is called when Server destroys the Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    // override stuff for application like getProperties() etc...
    @PreDestroy
    public void preDestroy() {
        // cancel all the Future<?> objects in the ManagedExecutorService
    }
}
```